# Tam quam magnum mundum est is grammatically correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, motto, italian-to-latin-translation

I translated the sentence “ Tam quam magnum mundum est” from the Italian sentences “tanto quanto è grande il mondo” (as big ad the world is, in English)
I wanted to know if the Latin sentence was correct

Answer (score 1):

*Tam magnus [est] quam mundus,* or *Tantus [est] quantus mundus.* (*Tantus* = *Tam magnus*.)